# init.d script won't rerun python script on error

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh

I am new to shell scripting and am having a bit of an issue when it comes to rerunning my script. My script is located here `/etc/init.d/receiver` and when I use the following command `sudo systemctl start receiver`, I get the following error,

`Job for receiver.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status receiver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

To test out the "retry" on crash, I purposely made a line in my python script that is being called to crash the program. That line is `someError = 'error`. Otherwise, the shell script which calls the python script runs with no issue but the whole point of this init.d shell script is to rerun the py script in case of an error and to start at startup. Here is my code,

```
#!bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             Test_receiver.py
# Reqired-Start:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:        $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:        3 4 5 6
# Default-Stop:         0
# Short-Description:    Rabbit consumer script Test_receiver.py
### END INIT INFO

set -e

# /etc/init.d/startup: start and stop the Test_receiver.py script
# no file /etc/default/startup for added config at this time

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

cd /home/cschoom/Security/src

run_receiver(){
   log_action_begin_msg "Starting Test_receiver.py"
   log_file=/home/cschuma1/otherfile.txt
   python Test_receiver.py 2>> $log_file
   retval=$?

   if [ $retval == "0" ]; then
      echo "success"
      log_action_cont_msg "No issues"
   else
      echo "failure" >> $log_file
      log_failure_msg "ERROR WITH TEST_RECEIVER `date`"
      sleep 5
      run_receiver
   fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
   run_receiver
   ;;
stop)
   echo "killing Test_receiver script"
   log_action_begin_msg "Killing Test_receiver.py"
   kill $(pgrep -f 'python Test_receiver.py')
   ;;
restart|force-reload)
   log_action_begin_msg "Reloading Peach_receiver.py"
   run_receiver
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage /etc/init.d/receiver (start|stop|restart|force-reload)"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac

exit 0
```

`

All I am trying to do is run Test_receiver.py, grab the return value, and based off that return value, either rerun the run_receiver function which calls my python script again or exit with 0 return code. This is a rabbitmq consumer script which will just run endlessly so I would like to rerun the python script as the fault will likely not be with the script but instead with what is being tested. (my python script runs tests, like nmap, on other machines). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: A bit OT, but why are you writing an *init.d script* in the first place? Wouldn’t it be *a lot* easier to write a systemd unit?

Comment: @Biffen I've said the same but my co-worker is familiar with init.d and insists that I use it.

Comment: Your coworker needs to learn systemd. It's far, far better than *init.d*. Push back.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I may do just that. I'm fairly certain I accomplished this with systemd already in fewer than 15 lines of code. Never got to testing it though